# Explanation of C code using random

Tags: objective-c, c

What does the following code do in obj-C -- how does it get a number between 0 and 1?

```
float prob = (arc4random() % 100) / 100.0
```

Comment: Do the math. It's pretty clear. But it gives a result from 0.0 to 0.99, not 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc4random()` returns a `u_int32_t` integer
mod'ing ('%' aka remainder operator) and will reduce the integer to the range 0 - 99
dividing by 100.0 (a floating point number) will force conversion to floating point and return a floating point number 0.00 - 0.99.

Better because it eliminates rounding bias is:

```
float prob = (arc4random_uniform(100) / 100.0;
```

Note: `arc4random()` and it's variants produces cryptography secure random numbers. It does not need manual seeding.

Comment: If the goal is to get a number from 0.0 to 1.0 then use `float prob = (arc4random_uniform(101) / 100.0;`

Comment: @rmaddy "from 0.0 to **and including** 1.0"

Answer (score 3):

From the [OS X manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/arc4random.3.html):

```
DESCRIPTION
 The arc4random() function uses the key stream generator employed by the
 arc4 cipher, which uses 8*8 8 bit S-Boxes.  The S-Boxes can be in about
 (2**1700) states.  The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random num-bers numbers
 bers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1, and therefore has twice the range of
 rand(3) and random(3).

 The arc4random_stir() function reads data from /dev/urandom and uses it
 to permute the S-Boxes via arc4random_addrandom().

 There is no need to call arc4random_stir() before using arc4random(),
 since arc4random() automatically initializes itself.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html)

It generates an `u_int32_t` random number. Modulo a hundred brings it in the 0 to 99 range (though it could be lower then 99). It divides this result to bring it in the 0 to 1 range.

So if it were to do 3006:

```
3006 % 100 = 6
6 / 100.0 = 0.06
```